# R function to find the vector with the highest correlation with all the remaining vectors

Tags: r, correlation

I want to find which vector (or row) in a matrix has the highest correlation value to the other vectors (rows). Is there another solution than doing this in a loop like this :

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5, 5)
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(mat)){
    # the correlation coefficients of each row
    cor_val[[i]][[j]] <- cor(mat[i,], mat[j,])
    # the average of the correlation coefficients of each row 
    cor_mean[[i]] <- mean(unlist(cor_val[[i]]))
  }
}

# the index of the row with the highest correlation
Indx <- which.max(cor_mean)
```

Comment: The line `cor_mean[[i]] <- ...` should be put to the first layer of nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is with `cor`. As pointed out by @Darren Tsai, `cor` calculates correlation by columns, but you can use `t` to transpose.

```
set.seed(3)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),5,5)

cor.mat <- cor(t(mat),t(mat))
max.cor <- max(abs(cor.mat[lower.tri(cor.mat)]))
which(abs(cor.mat) == max.cor, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   3   2
#[2,]   2   3
```

**Edit**
Forgot the call to `abs` in `which`, fixed.

Comment: I edited to include `abs` in the call to `which` 12 minutes ago. If that still doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: Oh it's my bad... I didn't refresh my web. By the way, `cor(t(mat),t(mat))` can be simplified to `cor(t(mat))`.

Comment: Yeah, I often am conflicted about providing an answer that is the shortest to type *versus* one I think the OP is likely to understand best. It's a tough balance.

Answer (score 2):

From your loop code, the corresponding shorter version is

```
which.max(rowMeans(cor(t(mat))))
```

However, correlation coefficients can be positive or negative. Computing the average will balance the strength of correlation. I think it's better to compute the mean of ***absolute correlation*** or ***squared correlation***. I.e.

```
which.max(rowMeans(abs(cor(t(mat)))))
```

or

```
which.max(rowMeans(cor(t(mat))^2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `cor(mat)` to obtain a matrix of correlation indexes. Since `Cor()` returns the correlation between columns, you would have to first transpose your matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),5,4)

mat <- t(mat)

cor(mat)
```

Comment: `cor` computes correlation between columns of a matrix. Not rows.

Comment: Then what about first transposing the matrix?

Comment: *I just noticed now that my answer does not provide the location of the highest correlation values, but @Ian Campbell does so - you may refer to it for a complete answer.